# Syntax error, insert ":: IdentifierOrNew" to complete ReferenceExpression How to fix that?

Tags: java, android

I am making an application.
But there are 2 errors when I try to run this app.
There's part of code with errors:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View_v) {
            Email = edittext1.getText().toString();
            Password = ediittext1.getText().toString()
            if (!((Email.trim().length() == 0) && (Password.trim().length() == 0 ))) {
                final ProgressDialog pg = naw ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); 
                pg.setCancelable(false); 
                pg.show(1); 
                pg.setMessage("loading...");
```

The error output says:

```
--------------------
1. ERROR in ...(location in mobile)
DriverActivity.java (at line 83)
  final ProgressDialog pg = naw
ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
pg.setCancelable(false); pg.show(1);
pg.setMessage("loading...")

                       ˆˆˆ
Syntax error, insert ":: IdentifierOrNew" to complete ReferenceExpression
--------------------
2. ERROR in ...(location in mobile)
DriverActivity.java (at line 83)
  final ProgressDialog pg = naw
ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
pg.setCancelable(false); pg.show(1);
pg.setMessage("loading...")

                       ˆˆˆ
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
```

I am using Sketchware for this app, because Android Studio is too difficult for me.

Thanks for answers for this question.

Comment: naw is a typo or what?

Comment: Your function decleration for onClick is also wrong, `public void onClick(View_v) {`, should be `public void onClick(View v) {`, no?

Comment: How to edit that public void in Sketchware? Please, answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue may be a simple typo in this line: `final ProgressDialog pg = naw ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);`

`naw` should be the keyword `new`.